# Bootstrap3 Nav Link Style with underline

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to style Bootstrap Menu as in Youtube with underline.

[image]

So far I have done below code but not achieving the effect ,
**border bottom is not working for a:active.**

I have added my css after the bootstrap css , so no possibility of override but still not working.

**Style CSS**

```
 a {
    color: black;
}


.navbar-nav>li>a:hover ,
.navbar-nav>li>a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ad1f2d!important;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
  <div class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @*<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../../img/logo.jpg" alt="77 Markets" height="100" width="100" style="margin-left: -10px; margin-right: 20px"></a>*@
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>                       
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]do you mean

```
ul li:hover:after{
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
   bottom: 0;
   content: "";
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/DZUPF/2/

Comment: No, I want border on active one

Comment: Have you tried adding !important e.g. border-bottom: 2px solid red !important; This will override any cascading and always apply the style, this will show you if it's an issue with over styles overriding.

Comment: I have added Important but not working , in the above code you are adding border to next one but I need active( user cliced/ selected) one.

Comment: The jsfiddle in the answer above 404s

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the !important attribute e.g.

```
a:hover {
  border-bottom:2px solid #ad1f2d !important;
}

a:active {
    border-bottom:2px solid #ad1f2d !important;
}
```

This will override any cascaded styles and will indicate if it an issue due to cascading styles.

The above seems to not work for you so how about this, wrap you navigation links in a div with an ID

the CSS

```
 #mydiv .navbar-nav>li>a:hover ,
 #mydiv .navbar-nav>li>a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ad1f2d!important;
}
```

and the HTML

```
 <div id="mydiv" class="navbar-collapse navbar-right collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>                       
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
```

Comment: Then why not simply: `a:hover, a:active { ... }` ?

Comment: Yes that's more succinct, I was using the same css posted so as not to confuse.

Comment: No not working on Active, Is there anything overriding by Bootstrap.  I have added my css after the bootstrap css , so no possibility of override but not sure , why a:active not working

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion and I hope i'm not wrong. Have you try to specify the border for all element? Is it working? I'm thinking that the underline effect and border bottom cancel each other. And also check bootsrap CSS file include because it may cancel your custom CSS if it is specified after your custom CSS include.

Comment: I have added my css after bootstrap. I have removed border effect no change, if I remove underline and keep only border , underline is not at all coming.